# GA4 Admin API properties.webDataStreams.getEnhancedMeasurementSettings seems to be broken

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-analytics-4

I've a .Net tool that gathers Admin data via the GA4 Admin API using the nuget package Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4.

We've recently noticed that our calls to getEnhancedMeasurementSettings suddenly started returning a 404 status.

Other API calls still work.

I've updated to the latest version of the package.

Also, the API explorer in the [Google docs for it](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.webDataStreams/getEnhancedMeasurementSettings) is also broken:

```
Cannot find specified method in converted discovery doc.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Can we agree that you are using this nuget package [Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha/) and not Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4. which gives you access to reports on GA4 and does not give you access to admin data.   Also GA4 is the new version of Google analytics and the reporting api would give you access to universal analytics data only.

Comment: You may just be completely using the wrong NuGet package. 
 The correct NuGet package for the GA4 admin api is [Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Analytics.Admin.V1Alpha)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha. The v4 in the other package distracted me. Maybe the minimal reproducible example is  the link to the docs I provided where their explorer does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getEnhancedMeasurementSettings method has been removed from the API as per the [Analytics API team public announcement](https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-api-notify/c/CkmWHBbB2Z4).